# How to make text of a button change according to a condition(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a project in VS C#, but I need some help. I have a Horizontal Split Container, Panel 1 of which contains a Menu Strip, and Panel 2 contains 2 more panels, Panel 1 of which acts like a Sidebar. I have added a button in the Menu Strip, which aims to hide or show the sidebar, depending on the condition `splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed == false`.
    However, I want the text of the button to change accordingly - eg. from "Hide Sidebar" to "Show Sidebar". How should I do this? 
Here is all the code:

```
    private void hideSidePanelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed == false) 
        {
            splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed = true;
        }
        else splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed = false;
    }
```

And here is a Screenshot:
[Something like this. I am unable to show the list of the View button, because of the program I am using, but I hope you get the point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNXk.png)

Comment: FYI you can replace your code with `splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed = !splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed;`

Comment: Thx. I am a beginner and didn't know that. :-)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW Ok. Tag added - Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the .Text property of the Button / ToolStripItem:

```
private void hideSidePanelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed == false) 
    {
        splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed = true;
        hideSidePanelToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Show Sidebar"
    }
    else {
        splitContainer2.Panel1Collapsed = false;
        hideSidePanelToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Hide Sidebar"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, strangely enough, it works only the first time!? But after a second test, the button does not change text. :-0

Comment: That is strange. There are a few things that could be going wrong. If I were you I would check for the following:

Comment: Check if other methods are changing the text, if the splitcontainer panel does indeed collapse, and that you're changing the text on the correct button.

Comment: Split container does collapse, button is only one. I might try the "Text Changed" property.

Comment: YESSSS! I put the .Text properties in a separate if () else; operator and now it works. The question is, why!?

Comment: It just occured to me, did you add brackets for the else operation? Since it only worked once, it could be that the text always changed to "Hide Sidebar" OUTSIDE of the If () else operation.